# An internal error when trying to upload a shapefile on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I was trying to upload a shapefile that was created in QGIS onto Google Earth Engine. I used the suggested way to do this on google (developers.google.com/earth-engine/importing), which involves adding a new "Table asset" and after about 15 minutes of the Tasks tab attempting to "ingest" the code, it returns an error which only reads "Error: Internal error.". I am wondering about how to fix this issue, or what I could be doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You mention you "used the suggested way to do this on Google".   Could you link and/or elaborate?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/importing This is the way that it suggests, and in specific the first section titled "Importing table assets"

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error message and contacted the Earth Engine team to see if they could help me figure it out. My problem was that there were rows in my shapefile that did not have any information, so the geometry column for those rows was converted to "NaN" on the upload. That caused problems for their servers while trying to ingest the shapefile, hence the internal error. The person I talked to also said that the Earth Engine team is working on improving the error messaging for internal errors, so hopefully, next time you try to upload, you can get a better idea of what is going wrong. Hopes this helps!